# Multiple loess lines in r

Tags: r, loess

I can create a loess line in R, based on a column of dates and a second column of values. Having loaded the dataset, I visualise one column of data below:

```
scatter.smooth(x=1:length(goals$Value), y=goals$Value)
```

However, how do I add multiple loess lines for additional columns? What would be the code to plot all the loess lines in one graphic? Say, each additional column is named Value2, Value3, Value4 etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't yet considered it, the package `ggplot2` makes such graphing problems significantly easier to handle, and gives nicer graphs:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame("days"=1:25, "v1"=rnorm(25), "v2"=(rnorm(25)+0.1))

#Reshape data from wide to long
df2 <- gather(df,var,val,c(v1,v2))

ggplot(df2,aes(x = days, y = val)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(aes(colour = var),se = F)
```

If you don't want to reshape the data, you could add individual lines like this:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x = days, y = v1)) +
  geom_point() +  #Add scatter plot
  geom_smooth(aes(colour = 'v1'),se = F) +   #Add loess 1
  geom_smooth(aes(y = v2,colour = 'v2'),se = F) +  #Add loess 2... and so on
  scale_colour_discrete(name = 'Line',
                        breaks = c('v1','v2'),
                        labels = c('variable 1','variable 2'))    #Define legend
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar outside the basics of R. I will install the ggplot2 library. I have the .csv file on my desktop. I've changed the working directory to the desktop. So which bit of the code above is loading the .csv? What does set.seed(123) mean?  If days have a maximum of 24 months, do I change it to  ' ("days"=1:24, ' ? Should additional columns, such as v3, v4, v5 etc, be added to the dataframe line? And does the final line need to be replicated for any additional columns such as geom_smooth(aes(y = v3),se = F)

Comment: You can read in your csv using `read.csv`; Imo and I used some sample data to demonstrate that the code works, as you did not provide a sample of the actual data to run the code on. If you read in your csv directly, you will not need the `data.frame` line separately. Lastly, yes, the final line would need to be replicated to add more loess lines.

Comment: This works perfectly. Is there a way of making each line a different colour?

Comment: I have edited the answer to include two methods (one involving reshaping the datasets using tidyr::gather, and the other without) that gives you different colours for each line.

Answer (score 1):

You would used the `lines` function:

```
# create test data
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame("days"=1:25, "v1"=rnorm(25), "v2"=(rnorm(25)+0.1))
# first plot
scatter.smooth(x=df$days, y=df$v1)
# add plot of second lowess line
lines(loess.smooth(x=df$days, y=df$v2))
```

to add color to the lines:

```
scatter.smooth(x=df$days, y=df$v1, lpars=list(col="red"))
lines(loess.smooth(x=df$days, y=df$v2), col="green")
```

Comment: `scatter.smooth` calls `loess.smooth`, which uses the `simpleLoess` function to generate the smoother. To ensure that other lines are created the same way, would it be better to do `lines(loess.smooth(...))`.

Comment: Thanks for this tip, @eipi10. I didn't know this. I'll make the edit.

Comment: This works perfectly, as does the the other answer below. Is there a way of making each line a different colour? If so, does R recognise colours as words, such as 'red', 'green' etc - instead of hex codes?

Comment: @user2020088 I added code above to draw the lines in different colors. to see a wider selection of what colors are available check the Color Specification section in `?par`.